# Finding a range of cells that contains specific values

Tags: vba, excel

I am new in VBA, so I am not familiar with all its capabilities. I have a worksheet with many "tables" in it. By tables, I do not mean actual Excel Table Object but chunks of data that are separated into "tables" via color/border formatting.

I can find which cell a specific table starts by finding the cell which contains "RefNum:". However, to avoid false detection of table, I would like to double check the next cells after it.

Essentially, what I want is not just to find "RefNum:" but to find the position of 3x1 array which contains the ff in correct order:

```
 - RefNum:
 - Database:
 - ToolID:
```

Only then can I be sure that what I found was a real table.

I am thinking of finding "RefNum:" and doing if-else for verification, but maybe there is a more sophisticated way of doing it?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:

```
Sub FindTables()
Dim cell As Range
Dim firstAddress As String

With Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(Rows.Count, Columns.Count))
Set cell = .Find("RefNum", LookIn:=xlValues)
firstAddress = cell.Address
Do
    'check cell next to "RefNum" and one after that
    If LCase(cell.Offset(0, 1).Value) = "database" And LCase(cell.Offset(0, 2).Value) = "toolid" Then
        'here, cell is first cell (ref num) of the table
        cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 4
    End If
    Set cell = .FindNext(cell)
Loop While Not cell Is Nothing And cell.Address <> firstAddress

End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for this. I am currently incorporating it in my module. However, I do not understand why is there a need to use "Lcase" in the If block. What if I really want the first letter to be in uppercase?

Comment: `LCase` is used to lower all characters within a string, so we don't miss anything due to capital letters. In other words, our condition in `If` is case insensitive. However, in `Find` method it is case sensitive.

Comment: @MichałTurczyn - Find can be case insensitive (MatchCase).

Comment: Thanks. So far, I made it partially work (though there are still some bugs I need to fix). I made some changes with your code. (1) I did away with the Lcase. I want the if condition to be case sensitive. (2) I used the Used.Range object instead of finding through the entire worksheet. (3) I used interchanged the offset indices i.e. (1,0) and (2,0) instead of (0,1) and (0,2)

Answer (score 0):

Based from Michal's code, this is the answer I came up with. It works well except for one thing. It does not detect the 1st cell address, only the 2nd and succeeding. Can anyone see where I made an error?

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub LogSum()

'Declare variables
Dim shtMacro As Worksheet       'Sheet where macro button is located
Dim Fname As Variant            'List of user-selected files
Dim bookLOG As Workbook         'Active logsheet file
Dim shtLOG As Worksheet         'Active worksheet from current active workbook
Dim WS_Count As Integer         'Number of worksheets in active workbook
Dim CellDB As Range             'First cell output for find "RefNum"
Dim FirstAddress As String      'Address of the first CellDB
Dim i As Integer, j As Integer  'Loop iterators


'Prompt user to get logsheet filenames
Fname = Application.GetOpenFilename("ALL files (*.*), *.*,Excel Workbook (*.xlsx), *.xlsxm,Excel 97-2003 (*.xls), *.xls", , "Open Logsheet Files", , True)
If (VarType(Fname) = vbBoolean) Then Exit Sub
DoEvents

'Iterate per workbook
For i = LBound(Fname) To UBound(Fname)
    Set bookLOG = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=Fname(i), UpdateLinks:=0, _
                  ReadOnly:=True, IgnoreReadOnlyRecommended:=True)      'Open workbook i
    WS_Count = bookLOG.Worksheets.Count                                 'Store max number of sheets
    Debug.Print bookLOG.Name                                            'Print the workbook filename in log

    'Iterate per worksheet in workbook i
    For j = 1 To WS_Count
        Debug.Print bookLOG.Worksheets(j).Name  'Print the current sheet in log
        Set CellDB = bookLOG.Worksheets(j).UsedRange.Find("RefNum:", LookIn:=xlValues) 'Search for "RefNum:"
        If (Not (CellDB Is Nothing)) Then
            bookLOG.Worksheets(j).UsedRange.Select
            Debug.Print "Something's found here."
            FirstAddress = CellDB.Address 'Assign the 1st search address
            Debug.Print FirstAddress
            Do   'Check cell next to "RefNum:" and one after that
                If CellDB.Offset(1, 0).Value = "DATABASE: " And CellDB.Offset(2, 0).Value = "Tester:" Then
                    Debug.Print "Yay! Got You"
                    Debug.Print CellDB.Address
                Else
                    Debug.Print "Oops. False Alarm"
                End If
                Set CellDB = bookLOG.Worksheets(j).UsedRange.FindNext(CellDB)
            Loop While CellDB.Address <> FirstAddress
        Else
            Debug.Print "Nothing found here."
        End If
    Next j
Next i

End Sub
```